# Partial Differentiation $ \frac {log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + (r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T} {\sigma \sqrt{T}} $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, partial-fractions

I'm having difficulty in finding the $ \frac{\partial d1}{\partial \sigma}$ for the equation below.

I tried using quotient rule but I'm getting $ -\sqrt{T} -\frac {log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + (r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T} {\sigma^2 \sqrt{T}} $ for $ \frac{\partial d1}{\partial \sigma}$

$ d1 = \frac {log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + (r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T} {\sigma \sqrt{T}} $

Comment: have you tried substitution

Comment: @Steven01123581321 I'm not sure how to use this method ? Any hint ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the quotient rule as you tried already yourself.

So $g(x) = {log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + (r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T}$

and $h(x) =  \sigma\sqrt{T}$

and $g'(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}(r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T = -T\sigma $

and  $h'(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}  \sigma \times \sqrt{T} = \sqrt{T}$

and then it is just applying the rule:

$$ \frac{-T\sigma \times \sigma\sqrt(T) - \sqrt(T)\times[log( \frac {S_0}{k}) + (r - \frac {\sigma^2}{2})T]}{(\sigma\sqrt{T})^2} $$

Comment: Thanks but your denominator is wrong. Should be $ \sigma ^2 T $ @Steven01123581321
If you simplify, you get my answer

Comment: Edited it: should be $(\sigma\sqrt(T))^2$.

Comment: So I assume my answer is correct as it's the same as yours @Steven01123581321

Comment: no, now my answer is different from yours...

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your answer ? It's the same @Steven01123581321

Comment: Didn't tried it, (I assumed you were commenting on my first answer, without the edit). so if it is the same, you have the correct answer.